# Почему dx.bat не находит java jdk?

Tags: java, компиляция

Я хочу скомпилировать `classes.jar`  и получить `.dex` модуль для дальнейшей его загрузки с помощью DexClassLoad. Однако при компиляции получаю следующую ошибку:

```
C:\Users\today\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.1>dx -dex -output loadable.dex classes.jar

ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

If you already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME environment
variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System Settings to point to the
JDK folder.

You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html
```

Однако JAVA_HOME у меня прописан, то есть путь к jdk в PATH уже есть:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8
```

Начинаю проверять find_java.bat:

```
PS C:\Users\today\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib> ./find_java.bat

ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

If you already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME environment
variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System Settings to point to the
JDK folder.

You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html
```

Джаву не находит

Comment: попробуйте не `JAVA_HOME `, а прям путь до java туда написать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что версия Java 11 не поддерживается, поэтому переход на версию Java 8 решил проблему и батник dx работает